# Are there any scientific papers on discriminant of extrema points of derivatives of 3rd order

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, reference-request

When we want to calculate the extrema points in one dimension we just need f'(x) =0 , f"(x)>0 to have local minimum for example

For 2 dimensions we have determinant
$D =  f"_{xx}(x,y)f"_{yy}(x,y)- f"_{xy}(x,y) $

But what if D is equal to 0?
Is there any research on derivatives of higher order?
And is there a discriminant for it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The 3rd order correction changes sign under $(x,y) \to (-x,-y)$. When 1st and 2nd derivatives vanishes, a necessary condition for extrema is **all** 3rd order derivatives also need to vanish. To determine whether it is a maxima or minima, one need to go to 4th order...

Comment: @achillehui So if  D is equal to  0 its enough 
 for all 3rd derivatives to be equal to 0 and and whether the 4th derivative of the whole funtcion F in that points is positive or not we can determine if it is  maximum or minimum???

Comment: @achillehui Isn't there a determinant  for this case too??For example for 2 dimention we say if D>0 and  $f_{xx}(a,b)$ is >0 (a,b) is local maximum. How can we determine if (a,b)  is minimum or maximum if D=0

Comment: If all 1st, 2nd, 3rd derivatives vanishes. it can be a local maximum ( eg. $x^4+y^4$ ), a local minimum (eg $-x^4 - y^4$) or neither (eg $x^4 - y^4$) I don't think there is a single number that can tell you whether it is a maxmium/minimum or not.